# How to display items in two columns in a ListView

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-8.1

I'm looking to layout a ListView in a Windows 8.1 app so that its elements wrap to (at most) two columns that read in order like a newspaper and scroll vertically, e.g.,

```
1 4
2 5
3
```

The closest I've gotten is:

```
<ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <WrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" MaximumRowsOrColumns="2" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListView.ItemsPanel>
```

but since [MaximumRowsAndColumns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.wrapgrid.maximumrowsorcolumns.aspx) is interpreted per the [Orientation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.wrapgrid.orientation.aspx), the result is

```
1 2
3 4
5
```

switching the [Orientation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.wrapgrid.orientation.aspx) to Vertical gives me

```
1 2 3
4 5
```

Am I going to need a custom panel to do this?  Another tactic is perhaps a gridview within a scrollviewer, but that seems a little hacky to me.

Comment: I think it would be wise to keep it that way itself, since if you arrange the news articles according to your need, it would mean that a latest article might go down (eg 3) to the bottom of the page, while an older article might bubble up (eg 4/5).. so the users would be reading the older articles instead of the latest ones. But there would be scenarios where we would want to  do what you need , hence my vote to you!

Comment: that's a very good point.. I don't have a temporal sort requirement here, but if one should crop up that would be a really strong argument for leaving it the way it is (along of course with that's the way it works out of the box and so users would expect consistency with other apps)

Answer (score 1):

You should use [ItemsWrapGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemswrapgrid) :

```
<ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <ItemsWrapGrid />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListView.ItemsPanel>
```

This will give you the result that you want :

```
1 4
2 5
3
```

Comment: not really since I lose vertical scroll capability... there could be say ten lines of two items each, while only three lines can show at a time, and I'd want to scroll vertically to see the other seven.  ItemsPanelTemplate will wrap at three lines and lays out similar to a gridview from what I can tell.